# Custom filter EU and non-EU countries in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

Most reports (if not all) can be filtered by country. Is there a way to create a custom filter for non-EU and EU countries.

The main report i want to filter on EU and non-EU countries is `Behavior > Site Content > All Pages` and `Behavior > Site Content > All Pages/Content Drilldown/Landing Pages/Exit Pages`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you just should create a custom filter, where you group EU countries and include or exclude them into filter.

Further grouping info is under https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034773?hl=en